# M2 Macbook Pro disable autoboot on charge

Tags: macbook-pro, power, charger

it seems like M1/M2 macbooks cannot disable autoboot on lid open, but is it possible to disable autoboot on charge (ie, when the charger is plugged in)?

(it's soo frustrating that this computer does not stay off when i turn it off...)

Comment: I have the same problem. When I want to charge the Macbook I'm using the USB-C from the monitor, but Mac turns on itself and the monitor.

Comment: See my answer @Maciej the order of connection can help both you and the OP.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to connect it to charge and then power it off or make sure you don’t introduce charge if you want it to not start up.

Note, if the clamshell is closed, the Mac won’t start until you raise the lid.